# Mtp not detecting Android in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: android, usb, mtp

Ubuntu is not showing my android device.

I tried to install libmtp* mtp* and also reinstalled it
And also try to put device information in udev.rules' relevant file

Comment: This is off topic. Should be posted in the ask ubuntu forum

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs on askubuntu.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use resetter software and reset libmtp* ,mtp* and other like jmtpf* from custom reset option (last one)

Dawnlode from Here
https://github.com/gaining/Resetter

Or get .deb file from here
https://github.com/gaining/Resetter/releases/tag/v1.1.2-stable

Extract it, install it and run

```
sudo resetter
```

In terminal and do above things

Comment: Not sure what this does but if it unintalls gvfs* packages that are not from your official repo, but the ones of your updated Ubuntu version... and installs the official ones, that would be good and after reboot seems to fix it.

Comment: Any command line equivalent without requiring external software (in ubuntu 20.04)?

Answer (score 6):

try installing `mtpfs`

`sudo apt-get install mtpfs`

and install `mtp-tools`

`sudo apt-get install mtp-tools`

if you have installed `mtpfs` and your device is still not recognized ( enable mtp mode on your device ) run `mtp-detect`

the output should look like this :

> Listing raw device(s)
>
> Device 0 (VID=1234 and PID=5678) is ...

followed by specific phone information

the `udev` editing can be done like :

open `/etc/udev/rules.d/69-libmtp.rules` with root. if this file does not exist yet copy it from `/lib/udev/rules.d/69-libmtp.rules`

in this file you add the following line ( with adapted vid, pid, ... )

`ATTR{idVendor}=="1234", ATTR{idProduct}=="5678", SYMLINK+="libmtp-%k", MODE="660", GROUP="disk", ENV{ID_MTP_DEVICE}="1", ENV{ID_MEDIA_PLAYER}="1"`

and reload udev

Comment: This worked but I have to change my USB setting on the phone away from MTP (eg. MIDI), unplug the USB cable and back to MTP and plug the USB cable back in.  The "Android" Nautilus window on ubuntu 16.04 LTS then pops up with "Internal storage" and "Sandisk SD card".

Answer (score 1):

This might be a simpler fix, it's what worked for me:

`sudo apt install mtp-tools`

Now plug in your Android phone via USB, cable matters so if one doesn't work try another.

`mtp-detect`

Done. Open up your Files app or terminal and transfer away!

Comment: Using a different cable worked for me! Funny enough, I used a `Cable Matters` cable.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone coming here for Ubuntu 18.04 like me, other answers didn't work. What did:

- Turn off USB debugging.
- Use USB to transfer files

Also, after doing this, android studio had some trouble recognizing the device even after switching debugging back on. Switching USB Preferences >> Use USB for "File Transfer" to "PTP" worked.